# deploy symfony project to namecheap cpanel

Tags: symfony, ssh, deployment

I have folder named App, this folder contain 2 folders on is back-end using symfony and apiplatform, and the other one is front-end is also on symfony I consume the API from the first one. I have SSH access to cpanel i create data base and I change the `.env` for two folders and i create subdomain also. and when I access to subdomain i see just index of contain the two folders. How I can deploy this?